# Datepicker is not working with bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I want functionality like the user can choose the date range. When clicking on first text box then the date picker should be open and the user can select the start date and the same for the second textbox for end date.

Below code, I have tried but it is not working, I console it and it will throw this `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function",` error...

Please help me to solve it.
Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="input-group input-daterange">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05">
    <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19">
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.input-daterange input').each(function() {
      $(this).datepicker('clearDates');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using `jQuery` instead of `jQuery Slim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing a few a scripts and link tags of `bootstrap datepicker`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- BootStrap 4 JS -->
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- BootStrap 4 CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- BootStrap DatePicker JS -->
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"
    ></script>
    <!-- BootStrap DatePicker CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"
    />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="input-group input-daterange">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05" />
      <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(".input-daterange input").each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker("clearDates");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```